# Programming an Arduino Uno. How to turn the values coming from a LDR(Light dependent resistor) into binary code output on the multi function shield?

Tags: c, arduino-uno

I hope that you are having a great day.
I have an assignment that demand me to turn the values coming from th LDR serial monitor into binary code shown on the LEDs of a multi function shield.
I also have to get the serial monitor to show the values in hexadecimal style.
The problem is that I am still new to arduino programming and sketches, and I am not sure what to do.
I apreciate all the help and every piece of advice!

```
int ldrPin = A0;              // LDR pin
int ldrVal = 0;               // Value of LDR

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);         // Initialise the serial monitor
}

void loop() {
  
  ldrVal = analogRead(ldrPin);    // Read the analog value of the LDR
  Serial.println(ldrVal);         // Show the value in the serial monitor

  delay(100);                     // Pause 100ms
}
```

//this is my code until now

Comment: @hcheung Thank you for your answer. I did a lot of research but found nothing regarding my assignment.

Comment: Really? I re-read your post a couple of times, I think the ability to elaborate and ask question is important here. Are you asking for help on how to interface with LEDs on the Multi-function shield that you didn't shown us? or you don't know how to print the data in Serial Monitor in hexadecimal (btw, try take a look at [Serial.println()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/println/) function).